# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException Misplaced argument matcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am getting the following exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

for the line of code

```
@Mock    
Template templateParser = new TemplateParser();
when(templateParser.getLayoutIdsFromTemplate(any(HashMap.class)))
                           .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("id1", "id2"));
```

The function I am mocking is as below

```
public class TemplateParser {
    public List<String> getLayoutIdsFromTemplate(HashMap<String, Object> parsedTemplate)
    {
        List<String> listOfLayoutIds = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Loading listOfLayoutIds here

        return listOfLayoutIds;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: It looks like you might be using the`@Mock` annotation incorrectly. Can you show your complete test class? (Or a minimal representative version)?

Answer (score 0):

Your mocked method `getLayoutIdsFromTemplate` is receiving a typed `HashMap<String, Object>` as parameter, not a simple `HashMap`. This is the cause of `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`.

If you can make a little refactor, you can solve it doing:

1) Change your method to receive a `Map<String, Object>` instead a `Hashmap<String, Object>`:

```
   public List<String> getLayoutIdsFromTemplate(Map<String, Object> parsedTemplate) {
      ...
   }
```

2) In your test class, match the parameter using `Mockito.anyMapOf(String.class, Object.class))` instead of `Mockito.any(HashMap.class))`:

```
when(templateParser.getLayoutIdsFromTemplate(anyMapOf(String.class, Object.class))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("id1", "id1"));
```

Hope it helps.